# Integration bounds for triple integrals in spherical coordinates (How do you reason about the bounds for $R$?)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

The following is the exercise I'm trying to do:

> Find the volume above the cone $z=c\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and within the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ using spherical coordinates.

Actually computing is trivial, so my question is concerning finding the bounds. I denote the spherical coordinates by
\begin{align}
x &=R\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi} \\
y &=R\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
z &=R\cos{\phi}
\end{align}
Finding the $\theta$ bounds is easy ($0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$), and using some algebraic manipulation to find the intersection of the surfaces, we can find the integration bound for $\phi$ to be $0\leq \phi \leq\arctan{\frac{1}{c}}$, for example using:
$$z=R\cos{\phi}=cR\sin{\phi} \Rightarrow \phi=\arctan{\frac{1}{c}}$$
Now, this is where I get confused. To me, to find the integration bound for $R$, we ought to consider the values of $R$ (which is the distance from the origin to the points which we are integrating over) given the restrictions by the other bounds. Thus, I drew this curde picture:
[image]
In my mind, the rightmost sketch (or $(1)$) is what we want to integrate, thus we have to integrate from some point $R>0$ (indicated by the small point) to $R=2a$. If we were to integrate from $R=0$ to $R=2a$, then in my mind, we would obtain the region in the rightmost picture. However, the answer states that the integration bound ought to be from $R=0$ to $R=2a$. Where is my thinking incorrect/ how should I go about reasoning to find the integration bounds?

The sources I have been looking over, and my professors methods have been very "hand wavy", so input would be much appriciated!

Comment: In your question, you should replace $R=2a$ with $R=a$.

Comment: @RobertZ , yes! Small typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Find the volume above the cone" means the volume above the infinite conic surface $z=c\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This infinite cone has no "base".  Therefore the range for $R$ is $[0,a]$ where $a$ is the radius of the bounding sphere and the correct picture is (2).

Hence, from your work, we find that the volume of the given solid is
$$V=\int_{R=0}^a\int_{\phi=0}^{\arctan(1/c)}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}R^2\sin\phi \, d\theta d\phi dR.$$

Comment: Right, Thank you!